# (python) tkinter scroll bar with user generated Entry fields

Tags: python, scroll, tkinter

I'm writing a tkinter GUI (my first one) and it is to colate data from user inputs.

anyway the way I'm doing that is as follows

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
textoutput = []
textbox = Entry(root, width = 5) 
textinput = []

x = 0 
offset = 0
yco = 40
press = 0 

textbox.pack()
textbox.place(x = 10, y = yco + offset) 

def addtextbox():
   global textinput, x, yco, offset, press, textbox

 offset = offset + 30
 txtinput = textbox.get()
 textinput.append(txtinput)

 textbox = Entry(root, width = 5)
 textbox.place(x = 10, y = yco + offset)



add = Button(root, text = "Add box", width = 10, command = addtextbox)    

add.pack()
add.place(x = 225, y = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem I'm having is that it gets to a certain point when there are too many text boxes to see and I need a scroll bar. I've tried using some sample code from effbot.org and some other places that I've googled but all they seem to do is scroll the background and not the text boxes themselves.

Any ideas ?

Cheers

Aaron

Comment: I think your indentation is a little weird with the addtextbox function.  Could you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (reasonably) simple class based solution.  The class is a tkinter canvas (which allows scrolling quite nicely).  I use the canvas as a geometry manager so that I can place the entry widgets wherever I choose (using the `create_window` method).

```
import Tkinter as tk    

class Manager(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self,master,**kwargs)
        self.widgets=[]

    def add_entry(self):
        entry = tk.Entry(self, width = 5)
        self.create_window(0,self._ypos(), anchor = tk.N+tk.W, window = entry)
        self.widgets.append(entry)

    def get_data(self):
        for w in self.widgets:
            print (w.get())

    def _ypos(self):
        return sum(x.winfo_reqheight() for x in self.widgets)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    manager = Manager(root)
    manager.grid(row=0,column=0)
    scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root)
    scroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.N+tk.S)
    manager.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
    scroll.config(command=manager.yview)
    b = tk.Button(root, text = "add entry", command = manager.add_entry)
    b.grid(row=1,column=0)
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text = "print stuff", command = manager.get_data)
    b2.grid(row=2,column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Suggested by @BryanOakley (Thanks!) (*untested*)

```
import Tkinter as tk    

class Manager(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self,master,**kwargs)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.create_window(0,0,anchor=tk.N+tk.W,window=self.frame)
        self.row = 0
        self.widgets = []

    def add_entry(self):
        entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        entry.grid(row = self.row,column = 0)
        self.row += 1
        self.widgets.append(entry)
```

Now do the other stuff as before to set up the scrollbar and you should be all set.

Comment: You can also use a frame in the canvas, then pack or grid the entry widgets in the frame.

Comment: @BryanOakley -- Thanks.  Also anchoring the widget by `tk.N+tk.W` is probably better than `tk.N` and then adjusting the position.  I've updated on both accounts

Comment: Hey thanks for the response\, I can't seem to get it to work, it seems like the scroll bar area appears but it wont allow you to scroll the region

Comment: You need to configure the `scrollregion` attribute of the canvas. It defines the area of the virtual canvas that should be managed by the scrollbar

Comment: The update from @BryanOakley seems to break the scrollbar. It doesn't seem that its state gets updated. No matter how many entries you add it stays disabled.